# Separate ApolloProvider component render with ReactDOM giving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have the following `ApolloProvider` setup inside `index.js` in my React application. It's working fine connecting to the Apollo server.

```
import { React } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import App from './App';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:5002'
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

export default (
    <ApolloProvider client = { client } >
        <App/>
    </ApolloProvider>
)
  
 const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
  
  root.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>,
  );
```

Now I need to decouple this I try to introduce a new Component called `ApolloProvider` inside a `ApolloProvider.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:5002'
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

export default (
    <ApolloProvider client = { client } >
        <App/>
    </ApolloProvider>
)
```

Then I try to render like the following in `index.js`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ApolloProvider from './ApolloProvider';

ReactDOM.render(ApolloProvider, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But here I'm getting the following error

```
ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead.
```

[image]

I tried few syntaxes with `createRoot` still no clear path for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the syntax used to render the app for React `v17` while you have installed React `v18`. You have two choices to make that warning go away:

1. Change `index.js` so that you use the setup for React `v18`:

> ```js
> import React from "react";
> import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
> import ApolloProvider from './ApolloProvider';
>
> const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
> // if you are rendering App as a normal component use this line:
> // root.render(<React.StrictMode><App/></React.StrictMode>);
> // the below line is specific to how the question is made:
> root.render(<React.StrictMode>{ApolloProvider}</React.StrictMode>)
> ```

2. Keep everything as it's but downgrade your React version. For that  replace the three lines below with what you have in  `package.json`, then run `npm i` and `npm start` :

> ```json
> "react": "^17.0.2",
> "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
> "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
> ```

Comment: thanks for your answer still I can see therer is error 'React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <ApolloProvider />.' but anyway I able to find a way by observing following documentation https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis

Comment: Did you try the first solution? I noticed that I didn't import `ApolloProvider`, did you?

Comment: yeah I tried option 1, giving some erros

Comment: It's because of the way you have your have exported your `AppoloProvider`, you could simply change this `root.render(<React.StrictMode><ApolloProvider/></React.StrictMode>)` to this `root.render(<React.StrictMode>{ApolloProvider}</React.StrictMode>)`

Comment: let me try again, let u know here

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution by observing the following documentation https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis

```
import App from './App';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import ApolloProvider from './ApolloProvider';

const container = (ApolloProvider, document.getElementById('root'));
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App/>);
```